# Get the value of title using xPath

Tags: xpath

I am using the following but it does not get me the value of the title

//*[@id="843285"]/td[3]/a[@title]

```
<a href="/match/843285/elche-vs-osasuna/" title="Elche vs Osasuna" id="g843285">Elche vs Osasuna</a>
```

Can someone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ways to find you the element directly, then use `@title` to get the title attribute. Note that your id is `g843285`, not `843285`.

If it's always `<a>` tag (otherwiser use `*` but with lower performance)

```
//a[@id="g843285"]/@title
//a[contains(@id, "843285")]/@title
//a[contains(@href, "match/843285")]/@title
```

I assume you don't know the match teams (otherwise you won't need to find out `title`), so the following won't work, posting here just for references.

```
//a[text() = 'Elche vs Osasuna']/@title
```

Comment: What if I wanted to get the text "Elche vs Osasuna" without using the id, is that possible?

Comment: @WalterTorres: From the HTML you showed, nope, you can only use either team names or that number to find the element. But there might be other ways depending on more HTML context.

Answer (score 0):

"Find the element whose ID attribute equals "843285", and return the value of its title attribute"

```
//*[@id="843285"]/@title
```

Comment: I thought that's what I did. I dont get your answer.

Comment: What you did was: Find the element whose ID attribute equals "843285", look for its third `<td>` child, then look for an `<a>` child of that which has a `title=` attribute. Quite different.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you're always dealing with `a` tags

```
//a[@id="g843285"]/@title
```

Otherwise do `//*[@id="g843285"]/@title`